# display image from database mysql in jsp

Tags: database, image, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

How I can display image from database MySQL in *JSP*?

And, how can I store the image in the database and not the path of it?
**I use only Servlet and JSP** .

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the image as a BLOB in the database. Later read the BLOB back and display it to the client. This [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/storing-image-in-oracle-database) shows an example of storing images in Oracle DB. However, if you want to store too many images, I would think storing them on file system and the path in the DB is a better option. You should take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) post.